# JMeter - what jorphan stand for

Tags: apache, jmeter

JMeter library have `jorphan.jar` which have JMeter classes (as JMeterError/JMeterException...)

JMeter code has `jorphan` package `org.apache.jorphan` which is related to Apache but I didn't find such Apache project or any project who uses it without connection to JMeter.

Is `jorphan` an old name of JMeter or old project that was merge into JMeter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JOrphan (JMeter Orphan) is a utility library that was created by one of JMeter commiters. He used accross different projects that’s why its package name is not related to JMeter.

See:

- http://markmail.org/message/xisc5fw2dr4bw4uy

I don’t know where it is used nowadays outside of JMeter

Comment: Do you know the meaning of the name JOrphan?

Comment: I guess it's *Orphan* because there's no specific project/owner for this library